# Can I use libspotify to play audio without using a low level audio API?

Tags: libspotify, qmediaplayer

Is it possible to use libspotify to obtain the URI of a track and play it using a higher level Media Player?  For instance, I'm interested in doing this with a QMediaPlayer in Qt.  I ask this because one of Spotify's sample applications uses lower level API's to write the samples directly.

I'd rather do this simpler, similar to how Grooveshark's API works by returning a URL for the track and simply setting that on the high level media player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to get audio for a Spotify track is using libspotify's audio delivery callback, which delivers raw PCM data.

Comment: I found this out a while ago, but thanks for answering anyway. :)

Comment: Oh! Whoops, didn't notice the timestamp on the question. Sorry!